# Show Total at the bottom of the Visual Table Tableau CRM

Tags: tableau-crm, tableau

I am just showing this below the Visual Table and wondering if there's a way to show the Summary at the bottom and not at the Top of the Table. I used the standard 'Show Total' option but could not move it to the bottom.

[image]

Is there a way?